# How to change default root directory where PStore files are saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, store

I'm using PStore to persist some really basic information in a pretty standard way,

```
@list_name = PStore.new(list_name)
```

How do you change the file location to not be root? I had a look around thru documentation but it seems to be pretty sparse

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass in the **path and name** on init

```
# create
@list_name = PStore.new('/tmp/wiki_pages.pstore')
# persist
@list_name.transaction {}
```

Look in tmp

```
$ ls /tmp|grep wiki
wiki_pages.pstore
```